# Rack app error: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmder

I am trying to run a Rails app on Windows 10 with the Cmder CLI. I encountered an error upon startup of the rails server.

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
*SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop 2018-04-27 23:07:32 -0400: Rack app error: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)>
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Never run rails on windows. They don't go together very well

Comment: Ok.  What do you suggest I run Rails on?  A Mac?

Comment: If you have one, sure. Otherwise ubuntu would do

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem.  My Ruby version was 2.5.1 and that is not a stable version yet, per my understanding.

I simply downgraded the Ruby version by installing Rubyinstaller again.  The version is now 2.3.3 and the apps run fine.

Comment: You might better update your rails project by `bundle update`. This should make it compatible to Ruby-2.5.